# Find minimum number of moves for Tower of London task

Tags: algorithm, math, shortest, pebl

I am looking for a solution for a task similar to the [Tower of Hanoi task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_london_task), however this is different from Hanoi as the disks are not constrained by size. The Tower of London task I am creating has 8 disks, instead of the traditional 3 or 5 (as shown in the Wikipedia link). I am using [PEBL](http://pebl.sourceforge.net/) software that is "programmed primarily in C++ (although you do not need to know C++ to use PEBL), but also uses flex and bison (GNU versions of lex and yacc) to handle parsing."

Here is a video of what the task looks like in action: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiBJ94HRpeM&noredirect=1

*Each disk is a number. e.g., blue disk=1, red disk = 2, etc.

```
    1            \  
    2         ----\ 
    3         ----/     3     1
    4  5         /      2  4  5
=========              =========
```

The left side consists of the disks you have to move, to match the right side. There are 3 columns.

So if I am making it with 8 disks, I would create a trial to look like this:

```
    1            \  
    2         ----\        7  8
 6  3  8      ----/     3  6  1
 7  4  5         /      2  4  5
=========              =========
```

How do I figure out what is the minimum amount of moves needed for the left to look like the right? I don't need to use PEBL to code this, but I need to know since I am calculating how close to the minimum a person would get for each trial.

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: Also, how does an environment for psychological experiments fit into this?

Comment: It would help if you told us what the "Tower of London task" actually is.

Comment: @interjay: you have three stacks filled with numbers. You also have a final configuration that has the same numbers but arranged differently. You need to transform the initial configuration to the final one in as few steps as possible. In each step you pop a number off a stack and push it to another stack.

Comment: There are less than 8!*3^8=10321920 different positions and no more than 8*9/2=36 moves needed. You can just enumerate all possibilities. Peanuts for the computers of today.

Comment: Well actually it's more like 1814400 positions, so even less work.

Comment: I recommend reading "The Tower of Hanoi - Myths and Maths" by Hinz & Klavzar.  Chapter 7 discusses the Tower of London variant.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is easy and its called breadth first search:

Each state has a certain number of successor states (defined by the moves possible).

1. You start out with a set of states that contains the initial state and step number 0.
2. If the end state is in the set of states, return the step number.
3. Increment the step number.
4. Rebuild the set of states by replacing the current states with each of their successor states.
5. Go to 2

So, in each step, compute the successor states of your currently available states and look if you reached the target state.

BUT, be warned, this can take a while and eat up a lot of memory!
You can optimize a bit in our case, since you can leave out the predecessor state.
Still, you will have 5 possible moves in most states. Which means you will have 5^N states to consider after N steps.

For example, your second example will need 10 moves, if I don't err. This will give you about 10 million states. Most contemporary computers will not be able to search beyond depth 15.

I think that an algorithm to find a solution would be easy and fast, but we have no proof this solution would be the shortest one.

Comment: I think you mean *breadth first.  Normally I wouldn't make that correction, but this is likely to be a starting point for people searching for it, so spelling probably matters.

Comment: Thank you, @recursive, wasn't sure at the moment. Will edit it.